# Assigh data add to [String:[AnyObject]]() not order by

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

I have problem with data that assign to array dictionary, and it is not in the order. This is my code you can test:

```
let arrayDataTest   = ["1","2","3","4"];
var myarray         = [String:[AnyObject]]()
var arrayAdd        = [AnyObject]()

 for i in 0...arrayDataTest.count - 1{
   var dayArray = [String:AnyObject]()
   dayArray["month"]    = arrayDataTest[i]
   arrayAdd.removeAll()
   arrayAdd.append(dayArray)          
   let string = arrayDataTest[i]
   myarray[string] = arrayAdd
}
```

Result for loop that i want is : **1,2,3,4** but my problem loop result is **4,2,1,3** . I don't know why? Thank

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How Are Dictionary Keys Sorted In Swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38616208/how-are-dictionary-keys-sorted-in-swift)

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have decalre `myarray` as of `dictionary` type not `array` type. In dictionary you can not control the order of `key`. So the output you are getting for your `for loop` it doesn't have any wrong output it is working correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Welcome mate, Happy Coding:) Is your confusion clear?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is equivalent to:

```
let myArray = ["1","2","3","4"].map { [["month": $0]]}
```

Note that, like in your code, `myArray` is an array of arrays of dictionaries and **each dictionary is contained in an array with exactly one element** (which is a bit strange).

`myArray` is `[[["month": "1"]], [["month": "2"]], [["month": "3"]], [["month": "4"]]]`

To get each element in order just do something like:

```
for element in myArray {
    print(element)
}
```

The output would be:

```
[["month": "1"]]
[["month": "2"]]
[["month": "3"]]
[["month": "4"]]
```